# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на форму value др формы присвоить текст?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Сделал вот так:

```
onClick="if(this.value=='Имя') this.value='';"
```

При этом он очищает его, но как сделать, чтобы если пользователь ничего туда не ввел и нажал на другую форму, вернуть туда прежнее value значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Имя')this.value = '';"
onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value = 'Имя';"
```

UPD: Конечно если наплевать на древние браузеры и все недобраузеры, то вот такой вариант шикарен

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя" />
```